# What is a way in grails to upload files to multiple users

Tags: grails

What is a way in grails to upload files to multiple users, (You select to who).  and then have the user access the files uploaded to him only(By sending him a URL path to those files: e.g http://localhost:8080/file_down/document/list?company=google. I want the gsp page to be the same for all the users, only the content stored in a table are different.  You do not need to write me some code I just want you to explain to me how it could be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file upload should be associated to a row in the database that defines what user it belongs to.

```
class UserFile {
  String name
  String location
  static belongsTo = [user: User]
}

class User {
  static hasMany = [files: UserFile]
}
```

Then in your view, you can just list links for the files belonging to a user.

```
<ul>
<g:each in="${user.files}" var="file">
  <li><a href="${file.location}">${file.name}</a></li>
</g:each>
</ul>
```

Something like that anyway.